# Transaction Failures from MetaMask

Tags: revert-opcode

I tried to send some Ether for an ICO (my first ever) but the transaction failed with error revert opcode. Please see below.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x17844dca601f11995b88411e768a363260e4a11d1ead9aeeb0b02acd61a44c5d

I tired a couple of times but it did not work and also increased the gwei to 99. I dont understand how this will work as the ICO has receommended that we use 200000 gas limit max and 60 gwei (max 99) when sending ether otherwise the transaction would fail. And now the sale has ended so missed out.

Can you please explain how can I avoid this issue next time?

Many thanks

Comment: I had the same issue .. how can we revert the transaction so that the ether comes back into the wallet?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19225)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19225)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug either in that contract or the person that's running the ICO messed up the ethRate (how much USD each ether is worth). They set it so each ether is worth. That contract has a limit of $5000 set per address. Therefore all addresses that send more than 0.00426417411 (5000/1172560) eth to the contract will fail because they're sending too much USD.

The ICO should have A. Gotten their ICO contract audited, which I'm assuming they didn't, and B. Had the ICO run by an automated migration so their wasn't any human error. If it was done by a migration script, they must not have run many unit/integration tests against this.

Comment: I think they did it intentionally to stop people buying more. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, I think another reason could be once the ICO hits its target limit all other transactions made after will fail with revert opcode to stop people wasting money on gas.